# sed starred group match not greedy without a running start?

Tags: regex, sed

I'd like to replace any number of a's or b's (really, longer strings, so character classes won't do), but the obvious thing fails:

```
$ echo xab |  sed -E 's/(a|b)*//'
xab
$ echo xab | sed 's/\(a\|b\)*//'
xab
```

I would have expected each of these to output just 'x'.
And with the + quantifier instead of the * quantifier, that's what happens.

Why is * not greedy here, and what's the best approach to this?

One workaround is to match everything first; e.g.

```
$ echo xq-as | sed -E 's/(foo|bar|xq)(-as|-gh|-ts)*/\1/'
xq
```

but doing that initial match is a challenge.

It's like the RE matching engine requires a non-starred something to warm it up.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `g` modifier to replace every match.

```
echo xab |  sed -E 's/(a|b)*//g'
```

Without this it only replaces the first match. And since `*` matches 0 occurrences, it matches the zero-length string before `x`.

You can see this if you do:

```
echo xab | sed -E 's/(a|b)*/FOO/'
```

the result is

```
FOOxab
```

Another solution is to use `+` instead of `*`, so it requires a match of at least 1 character.

```
echo xab |  sed -E 's/(a|b)+//'
```

Comment: Smart answer and faster than I again!

Comment: I'm going to dinner now, you can now answer other questions without me getting in the way :)

Comment: Thanks guys!  You sorted me out faster than I could blink.

Answer (score 1):

Your RegEx matches the beginning of the string where the asterisk matches zero occurrences of the capturing group.

See the difference (use a dot to visualize the match)

```
$ echo xab | sed -E 's/(a|b)*//'
xab
$ echo xab | sed -E 's/(a|b)*//g'
x
$ echo xab | sed -E 's/(a|b)*/./'
.xab
$ echo xab | sed -E 's/(a|b)*/./g'
.x.
```